# NGINX make directory readonly unless authentication provided

Tags: authentication, nginx, web, webdav

I have a directory `public`, where I will upload various files. I want those files to be downloadable without any authentication.
However, I also want to be able to edit and add new files using WebDAV, if authentication is provided. Is there any way I can have both behaviors on the same directory (location)?

I tried the following hack:

```
    location /public/ {
        if ($remote_user != "") {
            return 302 e;
        }
        auth_basic off;
        fancyindex off;
        dav_methods off;
    }

    location /public/e {
    }
```

However, I could not find a way to make `/public/e` index `/public/` instead.

I also tried the following:

```
    location /public/ {
        if ($remote_user = "") {
            auth_basic off;
            fancyindex off;
            dav_methods off;
        }
    }
```

But Nginx complained that I cannot have those directives in an if-statement.

I also tried:

```
    location /public/ {
        set $authenticated off;
        if ($remote_user != "") {
            set $authenticated on;
        }
        auth_basic $authenticated;
        fancyindex $authenticated;
        dav_methods $authenticated;
    }
```

But Nginx said a variable is invalid, `on` or `off` was expected.

I also thought about making two directories, `public` and `public-webdav`, which are symlinked to the same directory, and assign different nginx locations to them, but I was hoping for a cleaner solution.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it using this method:

```
location @public {
    auth_basic off;
}
location /public/ {
    if ($remote_user = "") {
        error_page 418 = @public;
        return 418;
    }
}
```

That is, creating a custom handler for error 418 (teapot) and forcing that error.